# How to create xaml vector images?

Tags: wpf, xaml, vector-graphics

I have been using xaml icons lately but still couldn't learn to create one. I am not a designer but would like to learn to create basic icons.

Is there any resource/tutorial that I can refer to learn the basics?

Any suggestion/reference would be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Templarian](http://templarian.com/2011/08/06/tutorial_creating_an_icon/) tutorial that create icons with Expression Design.